# Prevent Dialog animation when Activity stops

Tags: android

I have a dialog such as this:

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogSlideSideAnim);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.some_dialog_layout);

    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    dialog.show();
```

When the Activity stops, the dialog exit animation is shown on the home screen, and when the activity resumes the dialog is back in the place it should be.

How can I prevent the exit animation when the Activity stops?

Answer (score 0):

in your activity where the dialog is try putting in a cancel in the onpause

```
@Override 
public void onPause()
{
    dialog.cancel();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to cancel the Dialog, I will need it if the Activity resumes.

Answer (score 0):

```
static boolean isShow = false;

@Override 
public void onPause()
{
dialog.dismiss();
super.onPause();
}

@Override 
public void onResume()
{
if(isShow ){
dialog.show();
super.onResume();
}
}

//And where 
dialog.show();
isShow = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

**IMO**

1. Firstly, about dialog animation: If your devices animation settings are set to "No Animations" (Settings → Display → Animation) then the dialogs won't be animated no matter what you do
2. Secondly, you can use styles to change dialog exit animation:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
   <style name="PauseDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
       <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/PauseDialogAnimation</item>
   </style>

   <style name="PauseDialogAnimation">
       <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/spin_in</item>
       <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/slide_out_right</item>
   </style>
   ```

   *The windowEnterAnimation is an animation located in res\anim.*

   *The windowExitAnimation is an animation that is part of the Android SDK.*

Then initialize your dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.PauseDialog);
```

or

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation;
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks, but this is the same implementation as mine, so I don't see how this will solve it.